# Route::redirect with wildcard in Laravel 5.5+

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-routing

The new `Route::redirect` introduced in Laravel 5.5 is practical, but does it allow `{any}` wildcard?

Here is what I used to do in Laravel 5.4

```
Route::get('slug', function () {
    return redirect('new-slug', 301);
});
```

In Laravel 5.5, I can do the following:

```
Route::redirect('slug', url('new-slug'), 301);
```

Which allows route caching by getting rid of the closure.

**So far so good**, but what if I want to use a wildcard? In Laravel 5.4, I could do:

```
Route::get('slug/{any}', function ($any) {
    return redirect('new-slug/'.$any, 301);
});
```

Of course, I can still use this in Laravel 5.5, but my point is to be able to cache my route files.

Does the new `Route::redirect` allow the use of a wildcard, or **is my only option to use a controller**?

**EDIT:** What I am attempting to do is something like this:

```
Route::redirect('slug/{any}', url('new-slug/'.$any), 301);
```

Which of course doesn't work because I don't know where to reference the `$any` variable.

Comment: I just tested and it works (5.6 though) so i think 5.5 won't be an issue either. Edit: 5.5 also works

Comment: @Indra I have updated my question to show you what I am trying to do

Comment: You mean `artisan route:cache`? Yes it’ll still work

Comment: @ThomasEdwards It works indeed, but my question was about using `Route::redirect` with a wildcard in Laravel 5.5+.  `Route::redirect('slug/{any}', url('new-slug/'.$any), 301);` doesn't work, since `$any` is not specified anywhere.

Comment: I think it's gonna work. Try checking this PR https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/654

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use:

```
Route::redirect('slug/{any}', url('new-slug', Request::segment(2)), 301);
```

If you need to redirect with input data:

```
Route::redirect('slug/{any}', str_replace_first('slug', 'new-slug', Request::fullUrl()), 301);
```

Note that the above functions `url()` `Request::segment(2)` `str_replace_first` will be called in each request although there is no match for `slug/{any}`, nothing to worry about but I prefer to create my own controller in this case or add the redirect in the web server directly.