# Route::redirect with a custom url ( /products/{name} )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to redirect all "gets" from "/products/PRODUCTNAME" to "/product/PRODUCTNAME". I tried to do it with Route::redirect:

`Route::redirect('/products/{name}', '/product/{name}');`

But, if I go to "mypage.com/products/HJ-3000" it's supposed to redirects me to "mypage.com/product/HJ-3000", but I get, textually, "mypage.com/products/{name}".

I know I can do it with Route::get, but I want to know how can I do it with Route::redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
Route::get('/products/{name}', function ($name) {
    return Redirect::to('/product/$name');
});
```

**With Route::redirect**

```
Route::redirect('/products/{name}', str_replace_first('/products/{name}', '/product/{name}', Request::fullUrl()), 301);
```

[Route::redirect with wildcard in Laravel 5.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632994/routeredirect-with-wildcard-in-laravel-5-5)

**not tested